# antialiasing leaves thin line between adjacent widgets

Tags: c++, qt, antialiasing

I have two widgets that both have a dark background of the same color. These widgets lie in adjacent cells within a `QGridLayout` which has `ContentsMargins` and spacing of 0 on all sides. I use a custom `QStyle`-derived class for drawing.

If I don't use antialiasing, everything looks as expected - the two widgets' backgrounds merge into one continuous dark area. Turning on antialiasing (via `painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);`) leaves a thin (1px) white line between these two widgets.

Is it possible to somehow get rid of this line? Turning off antialiasing altogether is not an option as these two widgets have rounded corners and these look bad without.

**EDIT**

I made up a "minimal" example now:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPainter>

class foo : public QWidget
{
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
        QPainter painter(this);

        int x1, y1, x2, y2;
        int radius = 20;
        int diam = 2 * radius;
        rect().getCoords(&x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);

        QPainterPath path;       // This will be a rounded rectangle.
        path.moveTo(x1 + radius, y2);
        path.lineTo(x2 - radius, y2);
        path.arcTo(x2 - diam, y2 - diam, diam, diam, 270.0, 90.0);
        path.lineTo(x2, y1 + radius);
        path.arcTo(x2 - diam, y1, diam, diam, 0.0, 90.0);
        path.lineTo(x1 + radius, y1);
        path.arcTo (x1, y1, diam, diam, 90.0, 90.0);
        path.lineTo(x1, y2 - radius);
        path.arcTo (x1, y2 - diam, diam, diam, 180.0, 90.0);
        path.closeSubpath();

        painter.setPen(Qt::gray);

        // Comment out the following line and the rounded rectangles
        // will not have a thin boundary of background color between them
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

        painter.fillPath(path, Qt::gray);
        painter.drawPath(path);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGridLayout *l = new QGridLayout;

    l->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
    l->setSpacing(0);

    foo *c1 = new foo;
    foo *c2 = new foo;

    l->addWidget(c1, 0, 0);
    l->addWidget(c2, 0, 1);

    QWidget *w = new QWidget;
    w->setMinimumSize(500,250);
    w->setLayout(l);
    w->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I am working on ubuntu with Qt 4.7.3.

Comment: I don't know enough of qt to know if it's supported but what you need is compound shapes. If it's not supported you can use [antigrain](http://www.antigrain.com/)

Comment: Basically a good idea, but the problem is that AGG does not seem to integrate into Qt too well. I read a couple of usenet posts where people tried it, but it seems not too much came out of that, at least nothing with a good performance. But thanks anyway, I'll keep my eyes peeled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to shift by half-pixel, either when creating the path or by `translate(0.5, 0.5)` after setting the render hints.

Comment: OK, in my minimal example this really does the trick. Do you know why this might be the case?

Comment: I got my full code to work, too, where this .5px shift really did the trick in addition to some other pixel shifting. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's part of antialiasing rendering. See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qrect.html#rendering for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where these unsightly boundary lines are going to occur, you can just overwrite them with a straight gray line (which might need to be two or three pixels wide if anti-aliasing is still enabled). Not very elegant, but it does the job.

Comment: Yeah, that will definitely do the trick. However, as you say, it is not very elegant. Hence I was hoping that somebody had a more elegant solution.